# C++: Operator= overloading with polymorphism

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual Base& operator=(const Base& b);
};

class Derived : public Base {
    virtual Derived& operator=(const Derived& d);
};

int main() {
    Derived d1;
    Derived d2;
    Base *b1 = &d1;
    Base *b2 = &d2;

    *b1 = *b2; // <--
}
```

In the marked line why is `Base::operator=` function called and not the derived one called?

I thought that during runtime the compiler will evaluate `*b1` and see that it is a `Derived` object and evaluate `*b2` see that it is a derived object too and call the derived one.

**EDIT:**

Following the comments I would like to clarify why I didn't give the same signature for the virtual functions:
The reason I did the Base operator= function virtual is to tell the compiler to not statically link it during during compilation time but use the virtual table during runtime.
I also did the derived operator= function virtual to tell the compiler to add it to the virtual table and get rid it after doing all the static linking.

I don't understand why the operator the function is called on (*b2) is evaluate during runtime as Base and not derived

Comment: Because the static type of *b2 is Base.

Comment: They dont have the same signature.

Comment: @OHT - Forgive my ignorance... how do you know `Derived::operator=` was not called?

Comment: @jww: Ignorance forgiven. A print-to-console or a break-point can do the job easily...

Comment: Following your edit: The compiler "postpones to runtime" the decision of which function to execute, **only** if it sees more than one `virtual` function with **the same** prototype. In your case, there is only one function that takes `Base` reference and returns a `Base` reference, so the compiler can make the decision "on the spot".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer should be attributed to @imreal's comment (the functions have different prototypes).

Change this:

```
virtual Derived& operator=(const Derived& d)
```

To this:

```
virtual Base& operator=(const Base& b)
```

Of course, you may implement this function differently in each class...

Comment: Sure, but now it won't be a very useful assignment operator.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Depends how you implement it in the derived class.

Comment: Thanks @barak. I did not know you and OHT were working together sharing pasties ;)

Comment: @jww: You're welcome :) BTW, what do you mean by "sharing pasties"?

Comment: @barak - ah, my bad... sharing code offsite. Pastebins, not pasties. (I think pasties are what women use to keep their chest covered).

Comment: @jww: Hmmmm... Still doesn't make much sense, as we're not really sharing anything. BTW, what do you mean by "Pastebins"?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that in the derived class you **don’t** redefine the virtual (operator) function because it has a different signature. So in `Derived` you end up with two overloaded operators:

```
virtual Base& operator=(const Base& b); // inherited from Base
virtual Derived& operator=(const Derived& d); // defined in Derived
```

Comment: There aren't two matches; the static type of `*b1` is `Base`, so the compiler doesn't even consider the function declared in `Derived`.